# What is the meaning of "spoken of" in the last of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

I am reading a book, in which there is the following sentence.

> Some 150 of them are in the native Army, and beyond being quoted as somewhat dull, are very highly spoken of.

What does *spoken of* mean, in that sentence?

Comment: It denotes the peoples aor things you are talking about

Answer (score 4):

To be *highly spoken of* means to be "spoken of in a way that shows admiration or appreciation", "to be held in high esteem". When people are speaking about you in a certain way, that shows their opinion of you. If they speak highly of you, that means their opinion of you is high, i.e. good.

Answer (score 0):

It's [passive voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_%28grammar%29#Passive) of "(someone) speaks very highly of them".